# Overlapping between first record enddate and next record start date in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, sql-server-2016, gaps-and-islands

I have the below kind of data and I need below kind of output.

Input:

```
id   startdate  enddate
1    21/01/2019 23/01/2019
1    23/01/2019 24/01/2019
1    24/01/2029 27/01/2019
1    29/01/2019 02/02/2019
```

Output:

```
id  startdate   enddate
1   21/01/2019  27/01/2019
1   29/01/2019  02/02/2019
```

We need to use the logic of matching the first record `enddate` and nth record `startdate`.

Comment: Couple questions: [1] Are you really using SQL Server 2008? This product is no longer supported by Microsoft... [2] What have you already tried yourself? Show us your attempt so we can guide you better. [3] Why did you add the tag `common-table-expression`? Is this a requirement for the solution?

Comment: The question is clear from the input and output data samples, but you did not answer _any_ of the questions from my previous comment...

Comment: I am using SQL server 2016 and there is no condition to use only CTE

Answer (score 2):

This is a gaps-and-islands problem, where you want to group together "adjacent" dates. Here is one approach using window functions: the idea is to compare the current start date to the end date of the "previous" row, and use a window sum to define the groups:

```
select id, min(startdate) startdate, max(enddate) enddate
from (
    select t.*,
        sum(case when startdate = lag_enddate then 0 else 1 end) over(partition by id order by startdate) grp
    from (
        select t.*,
            lag(enddate) over(partition by id order by startdate) lag_enddate
        from mytable t
    ) t
) t
group by id, grp
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=5f246c900aa3aa5f8b1d665083f2d549)** - with credits to Sander for creating the DDL statements in the first place:

```
id | startdate  | enddate   
-: | :--------- | :---------
 1 | 2019-01-21 | 2019-01-27
 1 | 2019-01-29 | 2019-02-02
```

Answer (score 0):

have a look at

1. [NEXT VALUE FOR](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/next-value-for-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) method, works 2016 and later
2. Use a CTE or subquery (works in 2008) where you join on your own table using the previous value as a join. Here a sample script I use showing backup growth

   ```
   declare @backupType char(1)
          , @DatabaseName sysname

    set @DatabaseName   = db_name() --> Name of current database, null for all databaseson server
    set @backupType     ='D'        /* valid options are:
                                    D = Database 
                                    I = Database Differential 
                                    L = Log 
                                    F = File or Filegroup 
                                    G = File Differential 
                                    P = Partial 
                                    Q = Partial Differential
                                    */



    select  backup_start_date
          , backup_finish_date
          , DurationSec
          , database_name,backup_size
          , PreviouseBackupSize
          , backup_size-PreviouseBackupSize as growth
          ,KbSec= format(KbSec,'N2')
    FROM (
    select backup_start_date 
         , backup_finish_date
         , datediff(second,backup_start_date,b.backup_finish_date) as DurationSec 
         , b.database_name
         , b.backup_size/1024./1024. as backup_size

         ,case when datediff(second,backup_start_date,b.backup_finish_date) >0 
            then ( b.backup_size/1024.)/datediff(second,backup_start_date,b.backup_finish_date)
            else 0 end as KbSec
    --   , b.compressed_backup_size
         , (      
            select top (1) p.backup_size/1024./1024. 
              from msdb.dbo.backupset p 
             where p.database_name = b.database_name
               and p.database_backup_lsn< b.database_backup_lsn
                and type=@backupType
             order by p.database_backup_lsn desc
            ) as PreviouseBackupSize
    from msdb.dbo.backupset as b
    where @DatabaseName IS NULL OR database_name =@DatabaseName
    and type=@backupType
    )as A
    order by backup_start_date desc
   ```
3. using a "cursor local fast_forward" to loop over the data on a row-by-row and use a temporary table where you store & compaire prev value

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution with common table expressions that could work.

**Sample data**

```
create table data
(
  id int,
  startdate date,
  enddate date
);

insert into data (id, startdate, enddate) values
(1, '2019-01-21', '2019-01-23'),
(1, '2019-01-23', '2019-01-24'),
(1, '2019-01-24', '2019-01-27'),
(1, '2019-01-29', '2019-02-02');
```

**Solution**

```
-- determine start dates
with cte_start as
(
  select s.id,
         s.startdate
  from data s
  where not exists ( select 'x'
                     from data e
                     where e.id = s.id
                       and e.enddate = s.startdate )
),
-- determine date boundaries
cte_startnext as
(
  select s.id,
         s.startdate,
         lead(s.startdate) over (partition by s.id order by s.startdate) as startdate_next
  from cte_start s
)
-- determine periods
select sn.id,
       sn.startdate,
       e.enddate
from cte_startnext sn
cross apply ( select top 1 e.enddate
              from data e
              where e.id = sn.id
                and  e.startdate >= sn.startdate
                and (e.startdate <  sn.startdate_next or sn.startdate_next is null)
              order by e.enddate desc ) e
order by sn.id,
         sn.startdate;
```

**Result**

```
id startdate  enddate
-- ---------- ----------
1  2019-01-21 2019-01-27
1  2019-01-29 2019-02-02
```

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=adf33cf76c06ff691f0ec4e888329679) to see build up of solution and intermediate CTE results.